# How Can I update a fragment, using a FragmentManager?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I made some simple Fragments and know I want to update the content from an other Thread. But I don't know how.
If i would use simple Fragments, I could use a interface but in my case, this doesn't work i think.

I tried to use a Bundle and update it in Sequene, but this just works once, because I don't know how to call the method twice.

## Fragment

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class cf_Fragment_MainDriver1 extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARGS_MainDriver1 = "ARGS_MainDriver1";
    public static final String ARGS1_MainDriver1 = "ARGS1_MainDriver1";
    c_Thread_Update_Fragent c_thread_update_fragent = new c_Thread_Update_Fragent();
    private TextView tv_MainDriver1_counter;



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cf_fragment_main_driver1, container, false);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        String arg1 = Integer.toString(args.getInt(cf_Fragment_MainDriver1.ARGS_MainDriver1));
        ((TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.tv_MainDriver1)).setText(arg1);
        tv_MainDriver1_counter = root.findViewById(R.id.tv_MainDriver1_counter);
        updateData();
        return root;
    }

    public void updateData(){
        String x;
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        x = Integer.toString(args.getInt(cf_Fragment_MainDriver1.ARGS1_MainDriver1));
        tv_MainDriver1_counter.setText(x);
    }

}
```

## Thread

```
package com.example.fragmentmanagermain;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class c_Thread_Update_Fragent extends Thread {
    private static Fragment fi;
    private Bundle args;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        int i=0;

        while (true)
        {
            try {

                args.putInt(cf_Fragment_MainDriver1.ARGS1_MainDriver1, i);
                fi.setArguments(args);
                Log.d(TAG, "run: Works");

            }catch (NullPointerException e){
                Log.d(TAG, "run: Failed");
            }
            

            i++;
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void getFragment(Fragment f){
        fi =f;
    }
}
```

## Main

```
package com.example.fragmentmanagermain;

import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    c_PagerAdapter_Driver1 c_pagerAdapter_driver1;
    c_PagerAdapter_Driver2 c_pagerAdapter_driver2;
    c_Thread_Update_Fragent c_thread_update_fragent = new c_Thread_Update_Fragent();


    ViewPager viewPager;
    Button bt_Driver1;
    Button bt_Driver2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bt_Driver1 = findViewById(R.id.bt_Driver1);
        bt_Driver2 = findViewById(R.id.bt_Driver2);

        c_pagerAdapter_driver1 = new c_PagerAdapter_Driver1(getSupportFragmentManager());
        c_pagerAdapter_driver2 = new c_PagerAdapter_Driver2(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.MainPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(c_pagerAdapter_driver1);

        c_thread_update_fragent.start();


        bt_Driver1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setFragment_Driver1();
            }
        });

        bt_Driver2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setFragment_Driver2();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setFragment_Driver1() {
        viewPager.setAdapter(c_pagerAdapter_driver1);
    }

    private void setFragment_Driver2() {
        viewPager.setAdapter(c_pagerAdapter_driver2);

    }

}
```

So my question in this case would be, how can I use the public method updateData() from a secound thread?

Comment: You can try this code block : `fi.getActivity().runOnUiThread();` now put your `Runnable` inside of it and then post your value from that runnable to notify UI thread.

Comment: Just to be clear: It is working but only once, because I can call the function updateData() found in the fragment only once.
But I want to call it more often.

Comment: Omg Jesus. I don't know why but this works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the thing is that `updateData()` method of `cf_Fragment_MainDriver1` can be called from any thread you want but if you want to update UI of that `Fragment`, you must make a call from Main UI thread.

In your case, you're already *off-the-UI* thread called **`c_Thread_Update_Fragent`** & then you get to call your `updateData()` method from it *(which in case updates your UI)*. So, to do that you must be on **Main/UI thread**.

Therefore, simple solution would be that you're already having instance of `Fragment` object **fi** which can provide you hook to the main thread using it's **Activity context** from which you can use method **[runOnUiThread()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))** which takes `Runnable` as argument, that's why below code works:

```
fi.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Now you can make calls to fragment here like:
        args.putInt(cf_Fragment_MainDriver1.ARGS1_MainDriver1, i);
        fi.setArguments(args);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i Would Suggest to use Event Bus library. It a good way to communicate between diffrent threads.
Simply Send event and subscribe to an event

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: you can use this for communication between fragment and activities.